# How can i optimize this JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following JavaScript to toogle some information in my menu.

Is it possible to optimize it so I only have one function instead of n?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#km1").click(function(){
   $("#km1tog").slideToggle("slow");
 });
}); 

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#km2").click(function(){
   $("#km2tog").slideToggle("slow");
 });
}); 

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#km3").click(function(){
   $("#km3tog").slideToggle("slow");
 });
});
```

Comment: give them a class and use that instead of the id. `$('.km').slideToggle('slow');`

Comment: @MarkWalters class will hide all but OP want only particular item to hide.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed. Sorry I meant. `$('.km').click(function() { $(this).slideToggle('slow'); });`

Comment: looks like belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for loop and create an IIFE, to retain the value of `i`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i += 1) {
        (function(i) {
            $("#km" + i).click(function() {
                $("#km" + i + "tog").slideToggle("slow");
            });
        }(i));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#km1,#km2,#km3").click(function(){
    $("#"+this.id+"tog").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For a start you only need one `$(document).ready` call, so that will optimise it slightly. As for the rest, it depends greatly on the structure of the markup.

Ideally you wouldn't use ID's on the elements, you would simply reference them by their relationship, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".top-menu").click(function(){
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], function(i) {
        $("#km" + i).click(function(){
            $("#km" + i + "tog").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `$.each` with a hardcoded array instead of a `for` loop? Wut?

Comment: Do you know whether it is hardcoded in the actual example?

Comment: The OP hardcoded 3 id's. That's a bad practice, and shouldn't be encouraged. **Especially** if the suggested alternative is to hardcode all iterations of a simple for loop. Your code is saying: `for(var key in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10])` instead of `for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

If possible add a class to all of your "clickable" divs and try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".km").click(function(){
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#"+id+"tog").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('id');`... [You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/): `this.id`